# Create controller base class (partial)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, renderaction

Since my `@html.render` action crashes my dev and prod servers i have to use **partials(crap)**.

I tried creating `public partial controller{}` class so i can set needed data for all my views but i am having no luck (everything breaks).

I am coming from LAMP cakePHP background and really need simplicity.

I need to know how to create a partial base controller(**that doesnt override the regular  base controller**) and how to access multiple models from the class.

Thank you!

Comment: why can't you override the base controller?  Just create your own base controller that all your other controllers inherit from.  It's a recommend way to do it with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Added a comment to my answer about ViewData (this one is for you to get notification). Still, I'd suggest you to find out why RenderAction crashes (ask at SO, post exception trace, etc) since it's very useful for orthogonal data rendering.

Comment: ViewData["x"] for single object shouldn't throw errors. RenderAction shouldn't crash. You still haven't shown any error you experienced - nor from RenderAction not from ViewData["x"]. Without this information it's almost impossible to help. I agree that it's fun to keep trying the "hard way" - that is, yourself - but why asking here, then?

Answer (score 3):

```
public class BaseController: Controller
{
   public override OnActionExecuting(...) { ... }
   public override OnActionExecuted(... context) 
   {
       if (context.Result is ViewResult)
           ((ViewResult)context.Result).ViewData["mycommondata"] = data;
   }
   ...
}

public class MyController1: BaseController 
{
}
```

I.e. just derive from your new base controller class.

However I'd suggest you to ask here why your RenderPartial "crashes" - since it can be a better way for you, and it obviously shouldn't crash.

Comment: renderpartial works - its renderaction(futures) that crashes
and i need multiple data sets in my views - looking at the view model pattern now - but i really miss cakePHP(i could have had this done by now)

Comment: OK, RenderAction, but why and how it crashes? Why instead of fixing the problem you want something less suited for the problem? Also, if you need multiple data, why don't you use ViewData["data1"] = data1; ViewData["data2"] = data2. And, of course, you could have done this already; and if I had to write in CakePHP I'd say "I could have done this in ASP.NET MVC by now" ;-).

Comment: i tried setting viewdata['x'] and viewdata['y']
viewdata['x'] is a single object
viewdata['y'] is a list 
i can pass viewdata['y'] to a partial view but singular viewdata['x'] throws errors

i am still troubleshooting why renderaction crashes everything - at least i am still going - its fun to learn 'the hard way'

Comment: (+1) Could u provide more advanced example of the base class, please?

Comment: Advanced in what sense, what features you need there?

Answer (score 3):

better way to create base controller

```
    public class Controller : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    public shipsEntities db = new shipsEntities();

    public Controller()
    {
        ViewData["ships"] = db.ships.ToList();
    }
}
```

that way the rest of controllers follow regular convention

```
public class MyController : Controller
```